# I want to iterate in dataframe adding value( new column) in another dataframe

Tags: python, r, dataframe, iteration, mean

I have a dataframe with dates in one row: ej:

```
CULTIVAR/ START DATE / END DATE

x / 11.02.2020  / 11.02.2021
```

And Another Dataframe with a list of days and ambiental variables: ej:

```
 Date                Humidity

01.01.2020 /   80

02.01.2020 /   85

03.01.2020 /   90
```

I need a code to add the Ambiental Variables to the first dataframe acording to the match in the days. So if i need the mean Humidity from  the start date to the end date for the cultivar X, it goes to the second dataframe and iterates over the dates , maches them and add the mean humidity in the first dataframe.

Comment: You could start by writing a function that takes start and end date as parameters, and returns the mean humidity during that interval.

Answer (score 0):

An approach with **R** that adds `mean_humidity` to the first data frame by checking if the dates from `df2` fall within the given start and end date from `df1`

##### Example data

```
df1
  cul      start        end
1   x 2020-02-11 2020-03-22
2   y 2020-03-11 2020-03-12
3   z 2020-04-11 2020-04-11
4   o 2020-05-11 2020-05-11

df2
        date humidity
1 2020-02-11       34
2 2020-03-11       45
3 2020-03-12       26
4 2020-03-13       65
5 2020-04-11       67
6 2020-05-15       78
```

Use

```
df1$mean_humidity <- rowMeans(
  sapply(seq_along(df2$date), function(x) 
    ifelse(df2$date[x] >= df1$start & 
           df2$date[x] <= df1$end, 
           df2$humidity[x], NA)
  ), na.rm=T)

df1
  cul      start        end mean_humidity
1   x 2020-02-11 2020-03-22          42.5
2   y 2020-03-11 2020-03-12          35.5
3   z 2020-04-11 2020-04-11          67.0
4   o 2020-05-11 2020-05-11           NaN
```

##### dput() data

```
df1 <- structure(list(cul = c("x", "y", "z", "o"), start = structure(c(18303, 
18332, 18363, 18393), class = "Date"), end = structure(c(18343, 
18333, 18363, 18393), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18303, 18332, 18333, 18334, 
18363, 18397), class = "Date"), humidity = c(34, 45, 26, 65, 
67, 78)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```